# How to iterate through a relation in a single line in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `User` model which `has_many :tasks` and would like to do something like this:

```
 User.find([100,97]).tasks.each { |task| puts task.id }
```

but this deosn't seem to to work. I have tried

```
 User.find([100,97]).map(&:tasks).each { |task| puts task.id }
 User.find([100,97]).each.tasks.each { |task| puts task.id }
```

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: I know this what you asked, but this code is actually just retrieving the id from two keys and printing it. Why not: User.where(id: [100,97].pluck(:id)

Comment: See my updated answer for explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @lusketeer said, but the join is not necessary:

```
Task.where(user: [100, 97]).each { |task| puts task.id }
```

The reason it didn't work with your first example is `find` methods return an array, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation` so you cannot chain any more relation methods (e.g, `tasks`) on the result.

Your second example,

```
User.find([100,97]).map(&:tasks).each { |task| puts task.id }
```

will work but not quite how you expected. `map(&:tasks)` returns a two-dimensional array of tasks. Each top level element contains an array with tasks of a specific user. For this code to work you'd need to flatten the array:

```
User.find([100,97]).map(&:tasks).flatten.each { |task| puts task.id }
```

This will work although it's not efficient since it does a separate query for tasks of each user, making it an `N+1` situation.

Your last example,

```
User.find([100,97]).each.tasks.each { |task| puts task.id }
```

can also be made to work, it's just a syntax matter:

```
User.find([100,97]).each do |user|
  user.tasks.each { |task| puts task.id }
end
```

This is also the case of `N+1` query so it's not perfect.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
Task.joins(:user).where("users.id" => [100, 97]).each { |task| puts task.id }
```