# Active record associated objects on list of objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two Models: Region and Item with a has_many_through association.

I can write, as expected :

```
Region.find(4).items
```

What I'm trying to achieve is

```
Region.where(:id => [4,5,6]).items
```

This results in

```
undefined method `items'
```

Is there a simple way to do this ? Other than looping through the Regions and combining the results ?

Comment: it's the same case of this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337940/how-to-iterate-through-a-relation-in-a-single-line-in-rails-4/38337983#38337983)

Comment: try Item.joins(:region).where("region.id IN ?", [4,5,6])

Comment: This did the trick, thanks power. (just added () around the ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As power suggested, this is what I needed :

```
Item.joins(:regions).where("regions.id IN (?)", [4,5,6])
```

I added the () around the ? to make it actually work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query

```
Region.where(id: 2..5).includes(:hosts)
```

This return an activerecord relation. Each region object will have the associated hosts loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
result = Region.where(:id => [4,5,6]).map(&:items)
```

If you want single array then call `flatten` method on result.